# Why is this if statement is always returning true?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

My if statement, where I compare the name that exist to the name entered, is returning true even when I know the name I entered does not exist. It also says the if statement has an empty body.

```
boolean exists = false;
                for(University u : uniList)
                {
                    if(u.getDesc().trim().toLowerCase().equals(addUniDesc.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase()));
                    {
                        exists = true;
                    }
                }
                if(!exists)
                {
                    Map<String, Object> user = new HashMap<>();
                    user.put("Desc", addUniDesc.getText().toString());
                    db.collection("university")
                            .add(user)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                                    Snackbar.make(btnAddUni, "Added", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                                    addUniDesc.setText("");
                                }
                            })
                            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    Snackbar.make(btnAddUni, "Failed", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                            .setAction("Action", null).show();

                                }
                            });
                }
                else
                {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(getContext(), R.style.myDialog));
                    builder1.setTitle("University already exists")
                            .setMessage("Change something!")
                            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                }
                            });
                    builder1.create();
                    builder1.show();
                }
```

What am I doing wrong?

The result of this code is the dialog that the university already exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is right, and the value will be `true` due to the following:

This line below, has a `;` on the end: remove it and it will work as expected.

```
if(u.getDesc().trim().toLowerCase().equals(addUniDesc.getText()
                                         .toString().trim().toLowerCase()));
```

---

The `;` ends the `if` scope in this context. This means that the "scope" beneath:

```
{ 
    exists = true;
}
```

will always be executed.

Comment: You have got to be kidding me!! Will mark correct in 7mins.

Comment: You're welcome XD  ...  [btw: it happens to all of us ;-)]